# QGIS: Raster to Vector using Conversion tool but layer does not get created

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, convert

I'm trying to convert a raster image into vectors so i can import them into Illustrator later. Using the conversion tool seems to be quite straight forward in every tutorial, however it does not work for me and i am not able to read the protocol. Maybe someone is able to help me?
If i can provide anything to help you understand the problem, please let me know.

[image]

The log says the following:

```
QGIS version: 3.10.11-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: d2171173e4
Qt version: 5.12.3
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Polygonize (raster to vector)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False, 'EXTRA' : '', 'FIELD' : 'DN', 'INPUT' : 'crs=EPSG:25833&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=fgk_fl_wld&styles&url=https://www.brandenburg-forst.de/geoserver/IFGK/wms', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

GDAL command:
gdal_polygonize.py crs=EPSG:25833&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=fgk_fl_wld&styles&url=https://www.brandenburg-forst.de/geoserver/IFGK/wms /var/folders/rn/vb6tpqbn0s9256yrgvm8_5480000gn/T/processing_d24446e0553d4362a6dec642948e02ef/29722f8a26cc4599a109d7aaef0b0209/OUTPUT.gpkg -b 1 -f "GPKG" OUTPUT DN
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: styles: command not found

/bin/sh: /var/folders/rn/vb6tpqbn0s9256yrgvm8_5480000gn/T/processing_d24446e0553d4362a6dec642948e02ef/29722f8a26cc4599a109d7aaef0b0209/OUTPUT.gpkg: No such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 36, in <module>

from osgeo import gdal

File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/python/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>

_gdal = swig_import_helper()

File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/python/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper

_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)

File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module

return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic

return _load(spec)

ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/python/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: _iconv

Referenced from: <5EEEB96D-3955-332F-BD68-64BF110E0427> /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libfreexl.1.dylib

Expected in: <AE337682-E020-37D5-B1EF-E5350879881B> /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

Execution completed in 0.13 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/var/folders/rn/vb6tpqbn0s9256yrgvm8_5480000gn/T/processing_d24446e0553d4362a6dec642948e02ef/29722f8a26cc4599a109d7aaef0b0209/OUTPUT.gpkg'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/var/folders/rn/vb6tpqbn0s9256yrgvm8_5480000gn/T/processing_d24446e0553d4362a6dec642948e02ef/29722f8a26cc4599a109d7aaef0b0209/OUTPUT.gpkg</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

[image]

Comment: QGIS version: 3.10.11-A Coruña is ancient. Upgrade and it probably works.

Comment: It seem there is a problem with the output gpkg ? Could you show us your whole setting  for the tool you use ? Did you try to directly export to a format that Illustrator could import ?

Comment: I am trying to convert it into a shape file to later export it as a PDF or .dwg I attached a screenshot of the setting for the "conversion" tool i used (see above) :)

Comment: The raster layer you are trying to convert to a vector layer is a geoserver. You can't export a geoserver to a vector. Try downloading the raster and then converting to a vector.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The layer is from a geoserver ideed but unfortunatley the source doesn't allow the download. Next time i know what to look for though